Ratio of Area of Cross Section of "Prism"
Consider a solid similar to a triangular prism, but the angles of all faces (slants) with the base should be the same (Not sure if this solid has a name).
Now take a cross section of this solid parallel to its base, say at a height $h$ from it. Can we calculate the ratio of the area of the cross section and the area of the base as a function of the angle and the height?
If the base is a rectangle, this seems to look like a camping tent, but with all sides tilted equally. Now if the base is a random polygon this seems harder to visualize and the cross section might not even be the same polygon.
I searched a while for something along these lines, but could not find anything, any help appreciated.
Edit:
my best shot at describing this
This is a picture of triangular prism with rectangular base, but I'm more interested in cases where the base is whatever convex polygon. What i am trying to achieve (but am bad at drawing) is similar, except slants are equal. $\angle ABC = \angle BAC = \angle ADF = \angle DAC$

Truncated triangular pyramid?

Do you mean parallel to its base instead of perpendicular?

@Lieven, yes, small oversight, sorry!

@DavidG.Stork, I don't think so, truncated triangular pyramid seems like a pyramid without the tip, in my case I believe some solids would not even have the ability to have a tip if "continued"

Please post or link to an image of what you seek.

@DavidG.Stork Tried to make it a bit clearer with an image

Can this shape be called a hip-roof shape ?

@JeanMarie I think it could, but hip-roof seems more general, this would be a fixed slope hip-roof on a irregular polygon

Let's make a few assumptions here to avoid the worst complications.

The base is a convex polygon
All faces slant towards the inside of the polygon
The height $h$ of the parallel cross-section is sufficiently small (compared to the dimensions of the polygon) that the edges formed by adjacent faces do not intersect below it

Under those conditions, the cross-section is another (typically smaller) convex polygon with edges parallel to the edges of the original polygon. Projected on the base plane, the new polygon can be obtained by shifting all the original edges over a fixed distance $d$ towards the inside of the polygon, equal to $h$ times the cotangent of the slant.
In the case of a triangular base this implies that the two triangles are similar. The ratio between the areas is the square of the ratio between corresponding sides.
If an edge of the original triangle has length $L$ and the adjacent angles are $\alpha$ and $\beta,$ respectively, then the corresponding shorter length $l$ is
$$l = L-d(\csc\alpha+\cot\alpha+\csc\beta+\cot\beta)$$
and the ratio of the areas is
$$\left(\frac l L\right)^2=\left(1-\frac{d(\csc\alpha+\cot\alpha+\csc\beta+\cot\beta)}{L}\right)^2$$
The formula for $l$ continues to hold for $n$-sided polygons with $n>3,$ but then we can no longer count on similarity to compute the area of the smaller polygon. Each individual side contributes to the decrease of the total area through a trapezium with surface area
$$(\Delta A)_i=dL_i-d^2(\csc\alpha_i+\cot\alpha_i+\csc\beta_i+\cot\beta_i)/2$$
The total shrinkage in area is the sum of these contributions over all of the $n$ sides; in that sum, every angle is counted twice so we end up with
$$A_0-A=d.S-d^2\sum_{i=1}^n(\csc\alpha_i+\cot\alpha_i)$$
or
$$\frac A {A_0}=1-\frac{d.S-d^2\sum_i(\csc\alpha_i+\cot\alpha_i)}{A_0}$$
where $S=\sum_iL_i$ is the circumference of the original polygon.

I think you visualized this even better than I did when imagining it myself haha!
Could you please elaborate on how you got to the formula for $l$? This is the only point I do not follow

Draw a generic irregular triangle, then draw 3 lines parallel to the sides but shifted the same small distance $d$ towards the inside of the triangle. These new lines partition the triangle into 7 areas: one smaller but similar triangle; 3 diamonds in the corners, and 3 trapezia in the remaining space. Each of the diamonds has one angle equal to an angle of the triangle, and its heights (not its diagonals) are equal to $d.$

The decrease in length of one edge of the triangle can be measured by adding, for both of the diamonds formed near its two end points: the length of the edge of the diamond ($d$ divided by $\sin\alpha$), plus the length of the same edge but projected perpendicularly onto an adjacent edge of the diamond ($d$ divided by $\sin\alpha$ multiplied by $\cos\alpha$).
